# Identify this collection of SF short stores divided by era

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The first book of science fiction that I read when I was little was a collection of short stories that were divided by Eras: the Atomic Era, the Delphic Era, etc.  This book had great and powerful short stories that completely changed my life.

One of the short stories was something about the Flying Dutchman, some kind of space ship roaming the Earth after everybody was gone, until it run out of energy.

Another story that I remember, is set in the Delphic Era, when some doctors and scientists caught The Devil. After submitting him to medical procedures, they discovered the Devil was just a sick angel.

Another short story was "Christmas on Ganymede".

Please help me to find this book!

Comment: When were you little? Was it an old or new book then? Was it in English?

Comment: May help to include the year you read it, so people can rule out more recent works.

Comment: It was in the late 80s. I believe this book was from the 50s or 60s

Comment: @ClaudiaCastilloSmith I think you'll find the answer below -- I'm pretty sure that's the book you're looking for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After doing the Google search for "Christmas on Ganymede" to verify the title for my edit above, I believe I have an answer for you:

[*Adventures in Tomorrow*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?1660) appears to fit the criteria you describe, including having the specific story you mention by name, and essays named for various imagined future ages of humankind. The last story is "The Devil was Sick", which just from the title appears also to fit what you describe above.

Published in 1951, the anthology is long since out of print, but appears to be available from various used book sellers via (for example) Amazon.

Comment: Thank You so much!!!! I just bough it from Amazon!! You are amazing!!!

Comment: You're very welcome! Glad I could help!

Comment: Can't wait to receive it! It has been a long time I read that book and I totally lost all hope to find it!